# Command Substitution in find -exec

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, posix

I'm trying to extract the text of a bunch of pdf's with `pdftotext` using find:

`find /path/to/pdfs -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdftotext {} ~/Desktop/texts/{} \;`

However this doesn't work because `{}` contains full paths (and the paths can be different). So I tried using `basename`, however that doesn't seem to get executed by `find`.

`find /path/to/pdfs -iname "*.pdf" -exec pdftotext {} ~/Desktop/texts/$(basename {}) \;`

I also tried backticks and various ways of quoting the entire thing. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because the `$(basename {})` is executed before the `find` is called (shell expansions in arguments are evaluated prior to calling the command). Use the `find` like this:

```
find /path/to/pdfs -iname "*.pdf" -exec bash -c \
'dest=$(basename "$1"); pdftotext "$1" ~/Desktop/texts/"${dest%.*}.txt"' _ {}  \;
```

Note that some destination files may be overwritten if there are pdf files with the same base names in the directories searched.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` (if your `find` implementation supports it). This will make `find` change to the directory containing the file, and then invoke the specific command using the relative filename in that directory.

Of course, this approach will lose the full pathame from *any* instance of `{}` in the command line. That includes the destination of the file generated by `pdftotext`. However, from your description, that seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Yup, this. `find /path/to/pdfs -iname "*.pdf" -execdir pdftotext {} ~/Desktop/texts/{}.txt \;` The removal `.pdf` from target filenames can be a separate step if it's actually important. :)