# How to unrar from different subfolders into each specific subfolder?

Tags: command, unrar

I use this piece of command to unrar a bunch of files from a folder (which has a lot of subfolders).

All the unpacked files do end up in the same main folder though. How do I unrar every file to it's own subfolder?

find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o- {} ;

Example:

MAIN FOLDER

- SUBFOLDER
- file.rar

Ran the command, all files ended up in the main folder.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295965/how-to-use-find-exec-to-execute-command-in-directory-of-found-file-not-curre.

Comment: Thank you! "execdir" did the trick!

Comment: There is a similar question here on SO, I will flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command Substitution in find -exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719102/command-substitution-in-find-exec)